# Transforming functions

Tags: formatting, factorization

I am not familiar with *Mathematica* but have the following question:  I am trying to write *Mathematica* code that transforms $x^a+y^a$ to $(x+y)^a$ for any $x$ and $y$ and integer $a$.  I also need to transform $f^2(x)+f^4(y)$ to $(f(x)+f^2(y))^2$.

Answer (score 3):

I think we can just use basic pattern matching:

```
(* Freshman's dream... ahhhhh *)

FrobeniusFactor[expr_] := expr //. x_^e1_ + y_^e2_ :> 
  With[{g = PolynomialGCD[e1, e2]}, 
    (
      (x^Cancel[e1/g] + y^Cancel[e2/g])^g
    ) /; g =!= 1
  ]

FrobeniusFactor[x^a + y^a]
```

> ```
> (x + y)^a
> ```

```
FrobeniusFactor[f[x]^2 + f[y]^4]
```

> ```
> (f[x] + f[y]^2)^2
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This is not as versatile as Chip's method but it might be sufficient:

```
rule = {x_^a_ + y_^b_ /; Divisible[a, b] :> (x^(a/b) + y)^b};

{q^3 + r^3, f[x]^2 + f[y]^4} /. rule
```

> ```
> {(q + r)^3, (f[x] + f[y]^2)^2}
> ```